# Update HTML form with variable from previous form

Tags: html, django, forms

This should be pretty simple but I can't seem to figure it out and I can't find an answer online.

I have a website with three pages: On the first page the user submits a form which creates a GET request for the "park". The second page has another form which prompts the user for some more info which will be added to the query for the following page.

Now my question is: how can I append the GET query with the "park" from the previous form without asking the user to type it in again.

Here is some relevant code:

```
<form class="next-page" role="next-page" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8" action="/trip">

<div class="dates">
    <h1>When do you want to go?</h1>
    {{daterange}}
</div>
```

I want the subsequent page's url to look like:

> /trip?park=Zion+National+Park&start_date=04%2F12%2F2016&end_date=04%2F13%2F2016

If anyone can help, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture the value from url using `request.GET.get('start_date', '')`. You can do the coding like this in your view:

```
def someview(request):

     if request.method == 'GET':
          form = SomeForm()
          start_date = request.GET.get('start_date', '')
          end_date = request.GET.get('end_date', '')
          daterange = '{}-{}'.format(start_date, end_date)

          context = {'form': form}
          context['daterange'] = daterange
          return render(request, 'my_template.html', context)
     else:
        form = SomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('success_url')
```